# Is there any cost associated with private IP instance during idling in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Idling cost for a cloud SQL instance is irrespective of public or private IP?

Is there any idling cost associated with private IP for cloud SQL in GCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pricing for idle IP is fixed per region where your Cloud SQL instance is located and per type of DB you are using, not mattering if the IP is public or private.

You can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#top_of_page) for the pricings of Cloud SQL for each region and DB type.